# AutoRoute package throw WidgetsBindings error

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

I'd like to use the [AutoRoute](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#installation) package to manage my routes, however after installing and configuring it, I'm unable to run my app and receive the following error on the console.

```
: Error: Property 'window' cannot be accessed on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
../…/provider/auto_route_information_provider.dart:20
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1
Try accessing using ?. instead.
            location: WidgetsBinding.instance.window.defaultRouteName);
                                              ^^^^^^
: Error: Property 'window' cannot be accessed on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
../…/provider/auto_route_information_provider.dart:53
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by going to the library and adding a null check (?) to each lines of code that has throws that bug. You can easily navigate to the library code by using *ctrl* and tapping on the underlined reference code in your terminal